# How to check navigator.onLine in InAppBrowser for cordova/phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap, inappbrowser, navigator

I am developing an application in which I am loading a website into webview in cordova InAppBrowser. The problem is that suppose complete view is loaded and suddenly internet get disconnected, than If I clicking on any link, its giving me default browser error 'Page cannot be displayed, please check your Internet connection like'. I want to detect the internet connection availability before sending any request to load any link url. So I have tried using below :

```
if(navigator.onLine){
        console.log('NAVIGATOR IS ONLINE!!!');
        let ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.xyzabc.com', '_blank','location=no,zoom=no,disallowoverscroll=yes,clearsessioncache=yes,hidden=yes');
        );
```

but `navigator.onLine` is  checking only first load, not subsequent calls.

Please help me if anyone having any Idea. I want to show some nice, intuitive UI if it fails to connect with internet. Hope I am clear on my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use cordova network information plugin which does the job for you seamlessly. This plugin provides information about the device's cellular and wifi connection.
 official [website](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information) of this plugin